# Angular Material Tab inside tab Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

When I put one tab inside another tab using md-tabs and I try to change on upper tab in md-align-tabs attribute it reflects also in inner tab.

How can I stop this to happen

```html
<md-content  layout="column" layout-fill>
 <md-tabs layout="column" class="md-primary" md-selected="data.selectedIndex" md-align-tabs="{{checks[data.selectedIndex] ?'bottom':'top'}}" layout-fill >
      <md-tab id="Tab{{checkBottom}}" ng-repeat="checkBottom in checkDataBottom">
         <md-tab-label>Tab{{checkBottom+1}}</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
    <div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="left center">
           <md-checkbox ng-value="true" ng-model="checks[checkBottom]" ng-change="change()" aria-label="Align tabs to bottom?" style="margin: 5px;">Tab to bottom</md-checkbox>
           <md-content  layout="column" layout-fill>
              <md-tabs layout="column" class="md-primary" md-selected="data2.selectedIndex" md-align-tabs="{{checksX[data2.selectedIndex] ?'bottom':'top'}}" layout-fill >
                <md-tab id="Tab{{checksXy}}" ng-repeat="checksXy in checkDataBottom">
                   <md-tab-label>Tab{{checksXy+1}}</md-tab-label>
                   <md-tab-body>
          <div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="left center">
                  <md-checkbox ng-value="true" ng-model="checksX[checksXy]" ng-change="change()" aria-label="Align tabs to bottom?" style="margin: 5px;">Tab to bottom</md-checkbox>
                       </div>
              </md-tab-body>
                 </md-tab>
              </md-tabs>
          </md-content>
         </div>
        </md-tab-body>
       </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
```

Comment: Post your code here

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its some kind of bug in angular material.
But try to add

```
md-tabs[md-align-tabs="top"] > md-tabs-wrapper{
    bottom: initial;
    left: initial;
    right: initial;
    position: initial;
    height: initial;
    z-index: initial;
}
```

to your CSS file, I think this will help.

Here is example in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRNmwV

Comment: it's on the same place now but it's getting hidden

Comment: This solution solved the problem when I was trying to reproduce it in codepen from angular material demo. But maybe you have some other bugs. It will be easier to help if you recreate the problem in some kind of codepen, jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: Can you just provide me the link of your demo, it will be very useful for me

Comment: I edited answer and now it contains codepen. You can manipulate `md-align-tabs` attribute and it will no longer affect inner tabs, like it was without that fix

Comment: It's working fine :) it's kind of one solution but I am using full view so I am using layout-fill instead of dynamic-height attribute.. in that its not working but lots thanks for this also